# how to use ng-show to display specific divs inside an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I have an ng-repeat div to dynamically display a set of div tags based on a dynamic list of items, that each have a unique Id , a type and a "title" value which are both strings and I have a click function assigned to each of them. When I want to click on one of these divs , I want to display an separate div associated to that clicked div and I want to do that using an ng-show which at the moment has a condition where the id of this item/div should be equal/equivalent to a 
scope variable I've defined in a controller associated with the html for this new div to be displayed.

The problem I'm getting is that every one of these separate divs is showing and assuming that all the ng-shows are true which shouldn't be the case and I'm not sure why this is happening as all the id's for the items are unique. I've printed out to the console and can't see anything wrong with the assigning of the variable but not sure if I've missed something with regards to the ng-show condition.

Here is what I have so far  in html with 2 div examples (don't worry about replicating all the styling, i just want to figure out what is going on with the html/angular stuff):

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  " ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id"  ng-click="onClick(item.id)">

  //first type div that is clickable
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <header class="text">
        <h1 data-ng-if="item.title" ng-bind-html="item.title"></h1>
      </header>
    </div>
  </div>

  //div to be displayed after associated first div type is clicked 
  <div class=" col-sm-11 row"  ng-show="displayMessage===item.id"   >
      <header class="col-sm-12 text">
          <h1  data-ng-if="item.title" ng-bind-html="item.title"></h1>
      </header>
      <p class="col-sm-12" > text about {{item.id]} </p>
  </div>

  //2nd type of  div 
  <div class="row"  style=" background: linear-gradient(135deg, #156570, #1e9d8b);">
      <h1 data-ng-if="item.title" ng-bind-html="item.title"></h1>
      <i class="ms-icon ms-icon-heart-rate"></i>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>

  //div to be displayed after associated second div is clicked 
  <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11"  ng-show="displayMessage===item.id">

    <div style="background: linear-gradient(135deg, #156570, #1e9d8b);"></div>

    <h1 class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12"  data-ng-if="item.title" ng-bind-html="item.title" style="color:#000"></h1>

    <p class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "> text associated with {{item.id}}
    </p>

  </div>

</div>
```

And here is the simple click function I have . $scope.displayMessage is defined earlier on during the controller setup where its set to an empty string:

```
$scope.onClick = function (itemId) {
    $scope.displayMessage = itemId;
}
```

Let me know if I need to add more code.

Comment: Can you format your code? It is hard to read.

Comment: Just approved an edit. Let me know if there is anything else I can do to improve it

Comment: It looks ok now, can you post your item array? Your items may not have unique ids. Also it would be helpful if you can create a plnkr that represents your problem.

Comment: The items I did have for when I've been trying to test were different and the same problem occurred. How do I create a plnkr ? Haven't done a question for a while and just saw that you can do them now having looked at other questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done in a simpler way without adding property to the **items** varible you have in scope.

Let the Controller be

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.div_=[]; 

  $scope.items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "first item"
   },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "second item",
   },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "third item",
   }
];

  $scope.onClick=function(index,row){
     $scope.div_[index+'_'+row]=true;
   }
  });
```

HTML will be like

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div style="color:red" ng-click="onClick($index,0)">DIV {{$index}}.0---click to show DIV {{$index}}.0_CHILD</div>
    <div style="color:blue" ng-show="div_[$index+'_0']">DIV {{$index}}.0_CLILD</div>
    <br>
    <div style="color:red" ng-click="onClick($index,1)">DIV {{$index}}.1---click to show DIV {{$index}}.1_CHILD</div>
    <div style="color:blue" ng-show="div_[$index+'_1']">DIV {{$index}}.1_CLILD</div>
    <hr>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Here an array named 'div_' is maintained to trace all ng-show value of all div.

Working plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/uhFdCXkmS4gB95c9bjTR?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. This new approach works for me. Do you know why the first version I had of this with the id's being used for ng-show condition did not work?

Comment: My pleasure :) First thing you have not placed ng-click in proper place. It should be in Child div. Otherwise on parent div click ng-click function will be invoked.

Comment: ah ok. yes I did spot that after I posted the question as i don't want the divs that I want to appear to have a click method as well. What about the ng-show always being true? is that just because the divs don't retain knowledge of the id's?

Comment: Second thing : You have given same ng-show condition for both child div. See the demo plunker according to your code [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/UlPOnBKBEmtblV9WE9r7?p=preview)

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean by that but confused why the ng-show condition is the same, when the id of each of the items is different and therefore should then return false for the other items that weren't clicked

Comment: Can you edit the Plunker and add the Items array you have ? So that I can see what the exact data you have in controller.

Answer (score 1):

This will be easier for you to accomplish if you had properties on each item to key off of.

For example,

```
$scope.items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "first item",
    isFirstDivSelected: false,
    isSecondDivSelected: false
   },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "second item",
    isFirstDivSelected: false,
    isSecondDivSelected: false
   }
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "third item",
    isFirstDivSelected: false,
    isSecondDivSelected: false
   }
];
```

This will allow you to add an ng-click to your children items.

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  " ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id"  ng-click="onClick(item.id)">

  //first type div that is clickable
  <div class="row" ng-click="item.isFirstDivSelected = true;">
    <div>
      <header class="text">
        <h1 data-ng-if="item.title" ng-bind-html="item.title"></h1>
      </header>
    </div>
  </div>

  //div to be displayed after associated first div is clicked 
  <div class=" col-sm-11 row"  ng-show="item.isFirstDivSelected"   >
      <header class="col-sm-12 text">
          <h1  data-ng-if="item.title" ng-bind-html="item.title"></h1>
      </header>
      <p class="col-sm-12" > text about {{item.id]} </p>
  </div>
  
   //more divs.........
```

Right now, there is no good way to for your application to know that any of your children divs have been clicked. There are other ways you can do this, but in my opinion, adding properties that are well defined and straightforward is the best way.

Comment: That's a good answer. what would happen if say I added another property e.g. Type  where all those with certain type "a" fall under the first div and under type "b" should be from 2nd div etc?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show hide rows under loop

```
<div *ngFor="let client_obj of dashboard_data.data.items ;let i = index"    >
      <input type="checkbox"   [(ngModel)]="div_['level_1_'+i]">
          <div [class.hide]="div_['level_1_'+i]"   >
             {{client_obj.value}}
        </div>
 </div>
```